# ImportError: No module named fenpy.sirah

Tags: python

I am currently working in the following directory ( my script and associated files are here)

```
/scratch/conte/v/vprithiv/Gmsh
```

While I give this line , it throws me that error mentioned

```
from fenpy.sirah.Sira import Sira
```

Sira is located in the following path

```
/home/vprithiv/Fen/Utils/fenpy/sirah
```

If I am running my script from /home/vprithiv/Fen/Utils

I am able to obtain the output, But can I do it from my current working directory and somehow import sira??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try and import a module (eg `import foo`) in Python, the interpreter first checks the list of built in modules, and then checks the list of directories given in the `sys.path` variable for a file called `foo.py`.

`sys.path` typically contains your current working directory as it's first entry, and then a list of standard package locations on your system.

If you are only going to be working on your system, and you know the path to your package is going to stay constant, then you can just add your package directory to `sys.path`.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/vprithiv/Fen/Utils')

from fendpy.sirah.Sira import Sira
```